# How do you calculate the number of elements in a jagged array in F#?

Tags: arrays, f#

I am new to F# and haven't found the answer to this anywhere. I am creating a jagged array that can hold 10 rows and 10 columns each with an increasing number of elements. The code I used for the array creation and printing is as follows:

```
    let jagged = [| for a in 1 .. 10 do yield [| for a in 1 .. a do yield 0 |] |]
    let mutable len = 0;

    for arr in jagged do
        for col in arr do
            len <- (len + 1)
            printf "%i " col
        printfn "";

    printfn "%i" len
```

The above code gives the following output

```
0
0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
55
```

Currently, I am calculating the number of elements manually but would like to know if there is a better way to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to calculate the length of a single array, you could use `Array.length`. But what you have is an array of arrays of different lengths, and you want to calculate the sum of their sizes. Rather than just give you the answer, I'll show you how you could use https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/ (a site by Scott Wlaschin that's a really terrific resource, BTW) to find the answer yourself. This page presents a series of questions to help you find the functions you're looking for: starting from question 1, you move to other questions and eventually to a list of useful functions.

Question 1 on that page is, "What kind of collection do you have?" The choices are "I don't have a collection and I want to create one", or "I have one collection I want to work with", or several other choices where you have two or three or more collections. Here, we have one collection we want to work with, so the page directs us to question 9.

Question 9 on that page has a bunch of choices I won't repeat here, but one of them is "If you want to aggregate or summarize the collection into a single value". That sounds like what we want: we want the sum of the lengths of the sub-arrays. So we go to section 14, which has a bunch of functions we could use. And halfway down the list is `sum` and `sumBy`. Those sound intriguing. The `sum` function "returns the sum of the elements in the collection"... well, no, that won't work, because our array contains arrays, not numbers. But the `sumBy` function "returns the sum of the results generated by applying the function to each element of the collection." And we know there's a function for finding the length of a single array: `Array.length`. (The page talks about functions that work on lists, but pretty much any function that works on lists has a corresponding function that works on arrays and a similar corresponding function that works on sequences. The few exceptions are for things like how you can have infinite sequences, but not infinite arrays or lists, so there's a `Seq.initInfinite` function but there's no `Array.initInfinite` or `List.initInfinite` function).

So now that we've found that, we just need to write it.

```
let lengthOfJaggedArray arr = arr |> Array.sumBy Array.length
```

And that's it. Instead of calculating the length by hand via two nested `for` loops, there's a one-line solution that's quite simple and uses built-in functions. All you needed to do was know what functions are available — and since the entire list of available array/list/seq functions can be a little daunting when you're new to F#, Scott Wlaschin has made a very useful resource to help make it a bit less daunting.